# Use Observables to handle caching API calls

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I would like to set up a cache by having a service hold a reference to a `BehaviorSubject` which will call an API endpoint initially and then emit that result. The tricky thing for me is figuring out how to set a TTL so that if XX seconds has elapsed it recalls the API endpoint instead of returning the last result.

Is this possible with RxJS, or would I need to set up my own timers to 'reset' the `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/26490/caching-http-responses#t=201703302006007086247
It's using `ReplaySubject` internally but you should get the point behind it and be able to use it for your usecase.

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect, I guess Documentation doesn't show up in the Ask Question search, nor Google search atm. Add this as an answer and I'll accept.